# How to identify which OcrWord is what I wanted with the OcrResult

Tags: c#, uwp, ocr

I have an image and I call the OcrEngine.RecognizeAsync(bitmap) to get the OcrResult.

I want to get the birthdate from the OcrResult.

The OcrWord contains the text what I want and also contains a rectangle.

But how can I know which OcrWord is what I need .

Is there a mature solutions about it?

Comment: What is the format of your birthdate? We should be able filter the birthdate from the OcrWord.

Comment: I just take the birthdate as a simple, there are too much information I need to extract from the image. I don't know how to deal with the rectangle, because capture the image from different device the rectangle is different.

Comment: Could you tell us more detail about the rectangle? Could you give us the image that you want to identify?